# jQuery hover and click events for a five-star rating

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems a little bit excessive, and was wondering if I can refactor this jQuery. I'm not sure if you need anymore information, or if it's possible just by looking at this script.

```
  var getActiveState;
  $(".modal-review__rating-order-wrap span").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass("is-active");
    var thisStar = $(this).parent().find("[data-rating-value="+getActiveState+"]")
    thisStar.removeClass("is-active");
  }, function(){
    var thisStar = $(this).parent().find("[data-rating-value="+getActiveState+"]")
    if(getActiveState){
      $(this).parent().addClass("is-active");
      thisStar.addClass("is-active");
    }
  });
  $(".modal-review__rating-order-wrap span").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("is-active");
    $(".modal-review__rating-order-wrap span").not(this).removeClass("is-active");
    $(this).addClass("is-active");
    getActiveState = $(this).data("rating-value");
    return getActiveState;
  });
```

This is applied to a 5 star system, wanted to show what the jQuery is affecting. When jQuery clicks on the star, it adds an `.is-active` class to the span, and also to the wrap.

```
<div class="modal-review__rating-order-wrap">
  <span class="icon-star" data-rating-value="1">
    <svg>star 1</svg>
  </span>
  <span class="icon-star" data-rating-value="2">
    <svg>star 2</svg>
  </span>
  <span class="icon-star" data-rating-value="3">
    <svg>star 3</svg>
  </span>
  <span class="icon-star" data-rating-value="4">
    <svg>star 4</svg>
  </span>
  <span class="icon-star" data-rating-value="5">
    <svg>star 5</svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't see the Unicode stars in [200_success's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/172098) on Chrome, so I made a version of their snippet with SVG stars from [an old meta.SO post of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306425):

```js
$('.modal-review__rating-order-wrap > span').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().attr('data-rating-value', $(this).data('rating-value'));
});
```

```css
/* Initial state */
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap > span {
    display: block; float: left;
    height: 30px; width: 40px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20width='80'%20height='30'%3E%3Cpath%20d='M17.5,12.5h-8.5l6.8,5-2.6,8.1,6.8-5,6.8,5-2.6-8.1,6.8-5h-8.5l-2.6-8.1z'%20fill='%23c0c0c0'%20stroke='%23c0c0c0'/%3E%3Cpath%20d='M57.5,12.5h-8.5l6.8,5-2.6,8.1,6.8-5,6.8,5-2.6-8.1,6.8-5h-8.5l-2.6-8.1z'%20fill='%23ffd83d'%20stroke='%23eac328'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-position: 0px 0px;    /* gray star */
}

/* Persistent state */
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap[data-rating-value] > span {
    background-position: -40px 0px;  /* gold star */
}
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap > span.active ~ span {
    background-position: 0px 0px;    /* gray star */
}

/* Hover state */
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap[class]:hover > span {
    background-position: -40px 0px;  /* gold star */
}
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap[class] > span:hover ~ span {
    background-position: 0px 0px;    /* gray star */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-review__rating-order-wrap">
  <span data-rating-value="1"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="2"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="3"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="4"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="5"></span>
</div>
```

Note that I had to add `[class]` as a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) hack to the last two CSS selectors, since otherwise the third selector (with `.active`) would override them.  (In 200_success's version, the `:after` pseudo-classes effectively serve the same function, but my version doesn't use them.)

I also made the inner spans into floating blocks to eliminate any whitespace gaps between them, since those cause annoying "blinking" effects when moving the mouse over the gap.  [Flex layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) on the outer div could be used to achieve the same effect.

Note that I've marked this "answer" as [Community Wiki](/help/privileges/community-wiki), since it's basically just an addendum to another answer.  I'd have posted it as a comment, but you can't include snippets in comments.  I didn't feel presumptuous enough to edit this into their answer directly, but if 200_success wants to do so, I'm happy to delete this "meta-answer".

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid excessive reliance on jQuery.  All of the **ephemeral hovering behaviour can be handled using CSS alone**, and I would recommend doing it that way, instead of fiddling around with the `is-active` class.

jQuery is only needed to set the persistent state when clicked.  In the click handler, you have a bug here:

> ```
> $(".modal-review__rating-order-wrap span").not(this).removeClass("is-active");
> ```

If you have **multiple five-star widgets on the page**, you would reset `is-active` on *all* of them.  Instead, you should be using [`$(this).siblings().removeClass("is-active")`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

I find `getActiveState` to be a weird name for a variable: it sounds like a name for a getter function.  The use of a variable also prevents you from having multiple widgets on a page.  I recommend storing the state in the DOM instead.

I've made a demo using ⭑ and ⭒ characters.

```js
$('.modal-review__rating-order-wrap > span').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().attr('data-rating-value', $(this).data('rating-value'));
});
```

```css
/* Initial state */
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap {
    color: orange;
}
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap > span:after {
    content: '\2b52';  /* ⭒ */
}

/* Persistent state */
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap[data-rating-value] > span:after {
    content: '\2b51';  /* ⭑ */
}
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap > span.active ~ :after {
    content: '\2b52';  /* ⭒ */
}

/* Hover state */
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap:hover > span:after {
    content: '\2b51';  /* ⭑ */
}
div.modal-review__rating-order-wrap > span:hover ~ span:after {
    content: '\2b52';  /* ⭒ */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-review__rating-order-wrap">
  <span data-rating-value="1"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="2"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="3"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="4"></span>
  <span data-rating-value="5"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but your Unicode stars don't work for me on Chrome. (They do show up on Firefox, which handles font substitution better.) [Here's a tweaked version of your snippet with SVG stars.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179536) Feel free to use it if you like. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest is caching your jQuery variables so you don't need to keep traversing the DOM to find them:

```
var $myModal =  $(".modal-review__rating-order-wrap span");
var $parent = $(this).parent();
```

Also, the application and removal of the `is-active` class is occuring a fair bit. Is it possible to lift the class up and apply it to an ancestor element higher up the tree, and have its descendents react to that instead?

Comment: This code is applying to a 5 star rating system. I have the .modal-review__rating-order-wrap (as a div around the spans - which are the stars), so `.is-active` is being applied to both the wrapper, and the individual stars.